# I need someone who is willing to actually answer this volume of revolution question!

Tags: calculus

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me so I could get going on these problems, but this is confusing me... and it's been holding me up for the last couple hours.

How can I find the volume of the solid when revolving the region bounded by $y=1-\frac{1}{2}x$, $y=0$, and $x=0$ about the line $ x=-1$? How could I set it up?

I'd REALLY appreciate if someone could take the time to answer this so I don't spend all night on one problem.

Comment: Can you imagine what shape has this solid?

Comment: You should not ask the same question twice.

Comment: Why does your title read "Please vote to close this, no matter what's inside. Also downvote this!" that is a very strange title to choose for a question on a math Q&A website.

Comment: I didnt put that. Someone must have

Comment: I don't see anyone has edited your question, this is the original title.

Comment: "I need someone who is willing to actually answer this volume of revolution question!" was what i put

Comment: Yes, exactly! It says "Please vote to close this, no matter what's inside. Also downvote this!". Why did you choose that title?

Comment: I don't think you're seeing what I see..... I put " I need someone who is..." "willing to actually answer this question"

Comment: Okay, since you can't take a hint, this title you put, really just asks people to come in and downvote and close your question. It says "I don't want to battle my problems, please solve them for me". The revelation that you asked it already an hour ago and got an answer makes things even worse. On a more active day this would have raced to -8 in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The shape is a triangle, vetrex are the points (0,0), (0,1) and (2,0). You can use tube methode: $V=\int_{0}^{2}2\pi x(1-\frac{1}{2}x)dx=\frac{4}{3}\pi $ units.

Comment: Tube method????

Comment: Tube method is also known as shell method.

Comment: you can also use shower method, $r(y)=1$ and $R(y)=2-2y$

Comment: shower method...?

Comment: shower method is the disc method but when you have a hole inside each disc.

Comment: the radius of the hole is $r(y)=1$ in our example and the big radius is $R(y)=2-2y$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$volume=\int\pi y^2dx$$

use limites $x=-1$ and $x=0$